# Question about the limits of variable initialization with the ternary operator in C++

Tags: c++, initialization, conditional-operator

I have been trying to practice replacing if statements in some of my code with the ternary operator. This resulted in the finding of an odd behavior I don't understand.

```
void plusMinus(vector<int> arr) {
 float pos, neg, zero;
 for(int num : arr){
     num <=0 ? (num == 0 ? zero++ : neg++) : pos++;
 }
 cout << pos/arr.size() << endl << neg/arr.size() << endl <<zero/arr.size() << endl;
}
```

Using two different vectors : [-4, 3, -9, 0, 4, 1] and [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, 0, 0]. The first prints -nan,.333 and .1667. The second prints 0.375, 0.375, 0.25. However, if I initialize pos in the declaration as shown below, the function works perfectly every time.

```
void plusMinus(vector<int> arr) {
 float pos=0, neg, zero;
 for(int num : arr){
     num <=0 ? (num == 0 ? zero++ : neg++) : pos++;
 }
 cout << pos/arr.size() << endl << neg/arr.size() << endl <<zero/arr.size() << endl;
}
```

Is there some limit to the ternary operator or is this just the limits of the web compiler I am using? The first two variables don't have any issues, but the third seems to occasionally have an issue initializing.

Comment: What value are you expecting an uninitialized `float` variable to have?

Comment: You need to initialize all of your variables since you increment them but never assign anything to them.

Comment: I found the difference between the two functions:  the second initializes the `pos` variable.  Since the ternary operator is the same in both functions, your question has nothing to do with the ternary operator.

Comment: I guess my question then should be why do the first two work and not the third?

Comment: Don't use `float` type for accumulation (unless you intend on exceeding the range of an unsigned integer).  In your case, making `pos, neg,` and `zero` as integers will make your program more accurate and faster.

Comment: Lastly, since a `std::vector` doesn't fit into a processor register, you pass it by reference; or by constant reference if it is not modified.  Otherwise the compiler has to make a copy to pass to your function; which may be costly in both execution time and stack space.

Comment: I only see 2 examples, where's this third one you speak of?

Comment: Since all the numbers in the output are between 0 and 1 I need the decimal places from a float. I am aware that I could pass the vector by reference, but this is part of a programing problem on hackerrank and so I did not write the arguments for the function. There are three variables not sections of code.

Comment: Pointless to speculate why sometimes uninitialized variables seems to have the value you want. It's always a bug and there are no guarantees. Just initialize them.

Comment: As mentioned above, `float pos{0} , neg{0}, zero{0};` or `float pos = 0 , neg = 0, zero = 0;` so you don't start with undefined values.  Also, your compiler probably warned you about this, do you have warnings disabled?

Comment: I don't have them disabled. Hackerrank might have them disabled on their end, but I have never seen a warning when doing this in the past. I suppose it could be a bug/undefined behavior.

Comment: If you're lucky, some debug builds might set variables to 0 for you but for release builds that does not happen.  It is up to you to give every variable its initial value.  Without that, its value is usually undefined not zero.

Comment: I was not aware of that with C++. The programing language I started learning with was java which gives variables a value by default. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: @raz143 C++ is full of rules that when broken will result in _undefined behavior_, meaning that there will not be any warning or error, but also no guarantee whatsoever on the how the program behaves. To learn C++ you _must_ follow an introduction that clearly explains these rules. Any decent introduction to C++ should immediately start by mentioning that variables are uninitialized by default when variables are introduced.

Comment: The good news is that most compilers and IDEs will warn you about some of those rules if you set the warning level above 0.  "x used without being initialized on line nnnn" would be in the compiler output for most modern C++ compilers with warnings enabled.